# The intersection of three planes is empty if and only if two of them are parallel and not coincident

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

See above. How would someone prove this true? (Assume that the planes are in 3-space).

Comment: There is a problem with the way you stated the theorem. In the current form, you can choose the same plane three times (all of them are parallel), and you have infinitely many intersection points.

Comment: To be clear, we are looking for a point of intersection belonging to **all 3 planes** simultaneously, right?

Comment: Easily seen not true. Take three planes that intersect along a line and move them parallel a bit so that they will have only pair-wise intersection, but not all three.

Comment: A general equation of a plane has the equation $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ for example, where $$a,b,c,d$$ are reals.

Comment: Not true. Think Toblerone.

Comment: @st.math I see the confusion... I copied this question from a past exam, but I guess he implied ''not all of them the same''

Comment: @NazimJ exactly

Comment: @A.Γ. I see what you mean, so is there a way to prove this using simple algebra? I could go about finding a counterexample that satisfies this, but this could take too much time under exam conditions

Comment: @JBuck Still would not be true. One can think of many non-parallel arrangements of three planes which do have no common intersection point.

Comment: Take three vectors $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3\in\mathbb{R}^3$ in a plane and consider the system $[A_1\ A_2\ A_3]x=b$ where $b$ is not in the same plane as $A_i$. It has no solution. Then interpret each of the three equations as an equation for a plane. Another way: take an (easy) triangle in $xy$-plane and consider three planes through its sides parallel to $z$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

If the planes support the faces of a triangular prism, they meet in pairs (along a line) but have no common intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption on your definition of "parallel":

> 2 planes are parallel if the angle between their normal vectors is $0^o$, and they **do not** coincide

Then for one direction, assume planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ are parallel.  Then given any 3rd plane $P_3$, the intersection is $$ P_1 \cap P_2 \cap P_3 = ( P_1 \cap P_2 ) \cap P_3 = \emptyset \cap P_3 = \emptyset $$

For the other direction, your statement is **not true**.  Consider 3 planes $P_1$, $P_2 $, $P_3$, arranged in such a way that:

- $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect at a line $l_1$
- $P_2$ and $P_3$ intersect at a line $l_2$ such that $l_1 \cap l_2 = \emptyset$
- $P_3$ and $P_1$ intersect at a line $l_3$ such that $l_1 \cap l_3 = \emptyset = l_2 \cap l_3$

Then there is no point in the intersection of the $3$ planes, however no $2$ of them are parallel.  Algebraically, you can test this by checking the cross product of normal vectors, $n_j \times n_k \neq 0$ for all $j\neq k$ where $j,k\in \{1,2,3\}$

Answer (score 0):

We can express the system of linear equations of the planes as an [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix), where the second plane is parallel to the first, hence the $k$ scalar factor:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
ka&kb&kc&e\\
f&g&h&i\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that $e \neq kd$ since it is assumed that the planes are not coincident.

Performing Gauss-Jordan [row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Row_operations), we now get:
$$ R_2=R_2-kR_1 $$

$$ \sim
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e-kd \\
f & g & h & i\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And according to the restriction defined above, $ e-kd \neq 0$.

Writing the second row in cartesian form of a plane:

$$ 0x+0y+0z=e-kd $$
$$ 0x+0y+0z\neq 0 $$

$$ \therefore x,y, z \in \emptyset $$

This implies that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to describe a counterexample would be:

> Imagine a cylinder; take three different (non-parallel) 
>    tangent planes to it.

If you must use an algebraic description (but be careful with assuming that you do; symbolic descriptions are not "more mathematical"), you could take the planes

$$ x=0 \qquad y=0\qquad x+y=1 $$

It should be easy to see that they can have no point in common, but just as easy to see that none of them are parallel.